# Unable to resolve Styled Component?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I am creating an application with react-simple-chatbot using expo-cli. This is how my component looks.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import ChatBot from "react-simple-chatbot";

class Trafficbot extends PureComponent {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Trafficbot",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#06153b"
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: "#ffff"
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ChatBot
        headerTitle="Speech Recognition"
        recognitionEnable={true}
        steps={[
          {
            id: "1",
            message: "What is your name?",
            trigger: "2"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            user: true,
            trigger: "3"
          },
          {
            id: "3",
            message: "Hi {previousValue}, nice to meet you!",
            end: true
          }
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Trafficbot;
```

But when I run the app it gives me an error like this.

```
ERROR
15:44
Unable to resolve "styled-components" from "node_modules\react-simple-chatbot\dist\react-simple-chatbot.js"
ERROR
15:44
Building JavaScript bundle: error
```

I look for a solution. Then I was able to find a solution which was to install the styled component dependency. Then It shows me an error saying that issue in the keyframe. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you!.